# Apache Cordova Gradle Memory Exception

Tags: android, cordova

1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

Answer (score 1):

By default, cordova runs with the `-Xmx2g` option, I'm not sure why something is overriding this with `-Xmx512M`

With recent versions of cordova you can set JVM args yourself:

e.g: `cordova build android -- --jvmargs='-Xmx4g'`

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/android/index.html#configuring-gradle-jvm-args

Comment: Hi Norman,Thanks for your reply where do I set cordova build android -- --jvmargs='-Xmx4g'?

Comment: it's the cordova command, you don't set it. You execute it.

Comment: Hi Norman, I use Visual Studio 2017 to run Cordova,someone suggested in gradle properties org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g I changed it but still it wouldnt work. 
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0 is this cordova build android -- --jvmargs='-Xmx4g' a command you are suggesting , if yes how do we run this?

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure how to do this in a Visual Studio managed project, but normally you just run the command in command prompt in the cordova project folder. The gradles properties file is a managed file so it will likely be rewritten by Cordova. The jvm args flag actually sets the value in the gradle properties file itself.

Comment: I tried   cordova build android -- --jvmargs='-Xmx4g' still it fails here is the message
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please read the following process output to find out more:
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: I think visual studio, or something in your environment is overriding jvm args.

Comment: Thanks for inputs might be I will uninstall Java8 and install Java7 or install in another pc, upping your answer thanks for your response.

Comment: @AllamKalyana You should be using JDK8 -- I'm not sure if JDK7 is still supported by Android SDK. I know their docs recommends using JDK8. I also know that Visual Studio no longer supports Cordova projects. It might be better to just not use VS for your cordova projects.